# Select Rows postgres SQL where Key = String for all elements of Jsonb Array

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

So I have a Postgres SQL table that has a column of the type jsonb array. Looks like this more or less:

```
[{"adi": "cat", "status": "ACTIVE"}, {"adi": "dog", "status": "ACTIVE"}, {"adi": "bird", "status": "INACTIVE"}]
[{"adi": "fish", "status": "ACTIVE"}, {"adi": "dog", "status": "ACTIVE"}, {"adi": "reptile", "status": "ACTIVE"}]
```

So I want to select rows that only have animals with status ACTIVE in column 2.

Any ideas of how to go about it?

Thank you!

Comment: So are you on a Postgress or MySQL database?

Comment: postgres thanks for removing the tag

Comment: PLease dont spam tags, they are there to attract the right audience for your question. If you just spam a tag or 2 you just gather an angry crownd complete with burning tourches and pitchforks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the only two values are `ACTIVE` and `INACTIVE` you can use a SQL JSON/Path expression:

```
select *
from the_table
where not the_column @@ '$[*].status == "INACTIVE"'
```

Another option is the contains operator `@>`

```
select *
from the_table
where not the_column @> '[{"status": "INACTIVE"}]'
```

This returns all rows that do not contain a status with INACTIVE